# Perl Excel - Can't call method value on undefined value.. Deleting cells when text is a substring of another cell

Tags: excel, perl

I have the following code which parses an Excel file.. For every row, if a cell is substring of another cell on the same row, I want to delete this cell.

My data (in the .xls file) look like that:

```
Number1 Text1 Text2 Text3 ... TextN Number2 Number3 ... NumberN
```

Each number and each text is in a different cell. The number of numbers and text may vary per row.. I want to check if Text1 is a substring of `Text2` or `Text3` etc... similarly if `Text3` is a substring of `Text4 Text5` etc.. If they are substrings I want to delete these cells.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;
use diagnostics;
my $parser   = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new();
my $workbook = $parser->parse('test.xls');

if ( !defined $workbook ) {
    die $parser->error(), ".\n";
}

for my $worksheet ( $workbook->worksheets() ) {
    my ( $row_min, $row_max ) = $worksheet->row_range();
    my ( $col_min, $col_max ) = $worksheet->col_range();
    for my $row ( $row_min .. $row_max ) {
        for my $col ( $col_min .. $col_max ) {
            my $cell = $worksheet->get_cell( $row, $col );
            my $test = $cell->value();
            if (defined $test) {
                my $cellValue = $cell->value();
                print"The cell value is $cellValue \n";
            } else {
                print "Cell value is not defined \n";
            }
            #my $nextCell = $worksheet->get_cell( $row, $col+1 );
            #if (index($nextCell->value(), $cell->value()) != -1) {
    #print "$nextCell->value() contains $cell->value()\n";
#} 
            #next unless $cell;
        }
    }
}
```

I get an error `Can't call method "value" on an undefined value at ...` I believe it has to do with the fact that when the final cell in the row is found, the `$cell->value` function fails because the cell is empty.. I tried checking if the value if undefined so that I avoid processing this cell but I still get the same error.. How does Perl deal with empty cells ? How can I avoid getting this error? Thanks !

Comment: You stopped before the most crucial piece of information: `value at .... ` Where is this error?

Comment: Line 22 my $test = $cell->value();

Comment: It is the line before it which returns an undefined value, where `$cell` is assigned to. `my $cell = $worksheet->get_cell( $row, $col );` In the documentation it says: `Return the "Cell" object at row $row and column $col if it is defined. Otherwise returns undef.` In other words, that cell is not defined. Not sure how it could be that it is still within the ranges.

Comment: Thanks TLP. I think what bytepusher suggested is the solution to deal with the undefined error, now I need to find out how to delete the substring cells.

Comment: you might want to look into what TLP said: in a way, my suggestion is a fix, but like him, I am not certain why a cell should be undefined if within range. This might become a problem later or not be relevant, just keep it in mind if something else pops up that might be related.

Comment: Guys ofcourse I agree with both of you, but I think the problem has to do with the fact that the number of columns is not the same for each row... thus at some points it tries to refer to cells that do not exist in some row :) For example, the maximum number of columns is 14, but some rows has only 4 columns..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error means `$cell` is undef when you call `$cell->value`.

If you simply want to skip empty cells, why not add

```
next unless $cell;
```

in your `for my $col ( ... )` loop

Edit:

you could add

```
if( my $test = $cell->value() ){
$cell->delete if grep{ ( my $forward = $worksheet->get_cell( $row, $_ ) ) && ( $forward =~ /\Q$test\E/ } ( $col+1 .. $colMax );
}
```

Edit: This does not work ( I was not sure and could not test at the time ). Sorry.

Either declare a temporary variable $forward first, AND ( which was also wrong ) call ->value:

```
if( my $test = $cell->value() ){
my $forward;
$cell->delete if grep{ ( $forward = $worksheet->get_cell( $row, $_ )->value ) && ( $forward =~ /\Q$test\E/ } ( $col+1 .. $colMax );
}
```

Or, probably better, write it as a for loop (me was trying to be too smart for me own good)

```
for my $pos ( $col+1 .. $colMax ){

   my $forward_cell = $worksheet->get_cell( $row, $pos );

   if ( $forward_cell->value =~ /\Q$text/ ){
      $cell->delete;
      last;
   }

}
```

This, elegantly, goes back to my earlier point: This seems inefficient

However, it might be more efficient to first get all the actually existing cells and then delete, again grepping for a following cell that matches text. Not sure you want to do `/\Q$text\E/` or `/^\Q$text\E/` ( string begins with $text ), and you might not need `\Q ... \E` since it only escapes special characters and is unnecessary if there are none.

Comment: Yes that should do it, thanks :) Now I need to find how to delete the substring cells, any suggestions welcome.

Comment: edited with an answer attempt, but did not test, feel free to ask further if your experiments with my answer run into problems

Comment: Since my answer got an upvote, seems like it worked ;)

Comment: Actually you got the upvote for your first answer, I will check the second suggestion later when I have some free time :)

Comment: I get an error Global symbol $forward requires explicit package name. I think you have a missing right parenthesis at the 2nd forward by the way !

Comment: My bad. I kinda fixed it, BUT: I misread the question, you wanted to match the NEXT ONLY, I am matching ANY FOLLOWING. Thus, simply use your own $next_cell ( commented out ) and compare it, but do not compare index, compare `$next_cell->value =~ $test`

Comment: No i want to compare with any of the following.. i cant find a way to delete excel cells with perl, thats kinda weird

Comment: That makes sense, http://search.cpan.org/~dougw/Spreadsheet-ParseExcel-0.65/lib/Spreadsheet/ParseExcel.pm#Cell does not have a delete option ( which is probably good to keep the whole thing together ). Set the value to empty instead? Not sure what you want to do, but if you want to write it later, you have to do it that way.